# why wont this code parse my xml file

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have an xml file which I am trying to get the contents of and put into some html code. I have looked all over the web to find out how to do this and all tutorials same the same thing, which is to use ajax. Here is my code for the xml and the js, but it just wont work.

xml

```
<packages>
    <package_1>
        <heading>Package 1</heading>
        <title>WALK OF SHAME</title>
        <nights>1 NIGHT</nights>
        <price>&euro;55</price>
        <content>blah blah blah</content>
    </package_1>
    <package_2>
        <heading>Package 2</heading>
        <title>BALLS TO THE WALL</title>
        <nights>1 NIGHT</nights>
        <price>&euro;72</price>
        <content>blah blah blah</content>
    </package_2>
    <package_3>
        <heading>Package 2</heading>
        <title>THE CHASE</title>
        <nights>1 NIGHT</nights>
        <price>&euro;65</price>
        <content>blah blah blah</content>
    </package_3>
</packages>
```

js/jquery

```
$.get('content/packages.xml', function(d){
    $(d).find('package_1').each(function(){  
        var $pack = $(this);   
        var title = $pack.find("title").text();  
        var content = $pack.find('content').text();
        $('#package-form').append('<h1>' + content + '</h1>');
    });
});
```

any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You might need to specify "xml" as the AJAX return data type

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because `$(d).find('package_1')` only matches one element in your xml response. If you change your xml to respond with

```
<packages>
    <package>
        <heading>Package 1</heading>
        <title>WALK OF SHAME</title>
        <nights>1 NIGHT</nights>
        <price>&euro;55</price>
        <content>blah blah blah</content>
    </package>
    <package>
        <heading>Package 2</heading>
        <title>BALLS TO THE WALL</title>
        <nights>1 NIGHT</nights>
        <price>&euro;72</price>
        <content>blah blah blah</content>
    </package>
    <package>
        <heading>Package 2</heading>
        <title>THE CHASE</title>
        <nights>1 NIGHT</nights>
        <price>&euro;65</price>
        <content>blah blah blah</content>
    </package>
</packages>
```

and modify your each to `$(d).find('package').each(..)` maybe you will get what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for the reply but im afraid that approach does not work either